# Show that trace($\gamma$)=trace($\gamma^{-1}$)

Tags: curves

> Let $\gamma:[0,1]\to \Bbb C$ be a closed rectifiable curve and consider $\gamma^{-1}:[0,1]\to \Bbb C$ given by $\gamma^{-1}=\gamma(1-t)$. Show that trace($\gamma$)=trace($\gamma^{-1}$).

I tried to show that $\gamma$ and $\gamma^{-1}$ is equivalent, since equivalent paths has the same trace. However I found that they are not equivalent, since the $\gamma^{-1}(t)=\gamma\circ\phi$, where $\phi(t)=1-t$ doesn't satisfy the condition strictly increasing and also does not satisfy $\phi(0)=0,\phi(1)=1$.

Intuitively I believe this is true, but I am having trouble proving it.
Could anyone kindly help? Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you define the trace of a curve?

Comment: This is not (complex-analysis).

Answer (score 2):

The trace of a curve $\gamma:[0,1]\to \Bbb C$ (as I remember it)
is just the *range*:
$$
 \text{trace}(\gamma) = \{ \gamma(t) \mid  t \in [0, 1] \} \, .
$$
Then $\text{trace}(\gamma) = \text{trace}(\gamma^{-1})$ follows
directly from
$$
 t \in [0, 1] \Longleftrightarrow 1- t \in [0, 1] \, .
$$